Python can't see a new module in a directory it already imported from
In this test, I create a new directory (deleting it if it already exists), add it to sys.path, add two simple Python files, and try to import them. I'm using Python 3.11.6 on Ubuntu 23.10.
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import rmtree

d = Path('/tmp/fleen')
try:
    rmtree(d)
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass
d.mkdir()
sys.path = [str(d)] + sys.path

(d / 'module1.py').write_text('x = 1')
import module1
assert module1.x == 1

(d / 'module2.py').write_text('x = 2')
print('file contains:', repr((d / 'module2.py').read_text()))
import module2
assert module2.x == 2

This prints file contains: 'x = 2', as expected, but then raises
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 16, in <module>
    import module2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module2'

What's going on? Why can't import see the file? Is there some sort of cache of each directory in sys.path that I need to clear?
Edited to add: Unpredictably, this sometimes works, as if there's a race condition of some kind. This is mysterious because all the IO here is supposed to flush all buffers before going on to the next statement.

Some importers cache the modules they find. You have to invalidate the cache when another module is added. From importlib.import_module

If you are dynamically importing a module that was created since the
interpreter began execution (e.g., created a Python source file), you
may need to call invalidate_caches() in order for the new module to be
noticed by the import system.

By adding a line to invalidate importer caches after writing the second file, the problem is solved
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import rmtree
import importlib

d = Path('/tmp/fleen')
try:
    rmtree(d)
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass
d.mkdir()
#sys.path = [str(d)] + sys.path
sys.path.insert(0, str(d))

(d / 'module1.py').write_text('x = 1')
import module1
assert module1.x == 1

(d / 'module2.py').write_text('x = 2')
importlib.invalidate_caches()                 # <== invalidate
print('file contains:', repr((d / 'module2.py').read_text()))
import module2
assert module2.x == 2

This wasn't needed for the first file because /tmp/fleen hadn't been visited by the importer before the import.

Did you try adding an __init__.py file to the module you want to import from?
By the way, you can use sys.path.append(d) instead of sys.path = [str(d)] + sys.path

Append puts the modules at the back, so if there's another package with the same name (typically a different version of the same package) in your sys.path it will use the other one instead. This is an important distinction for version restricting imported modules.  Probably overkill in this particular example, but a real world example is I've had to overload numpy before to use the scipy that matched my python version.  Couldn't update python's packages due to separate versioning restrictions.

Good point, makes total sense!

Adding (d / '__init__.py').write_text('') doesn't seem to help.

OP isn't using fleen as a package so __init__.py isn't needed.

I'd prefer sys.path.insert(0, str(d)), which adds to the existing path list, over sys.path = [str(d)] + sys.path, which replaces the path list, just in case something else is referencing the same list. I tested, and it didn't make any difference in this case, but there could be other cases we don't know about here.
